# "Logging in and out" Of A Socket

Tags: java, sockets, connection, reset

I am in the process of developing a game and I have a question.

I have a client where a user can log in to the game or disconnect using a unique account stored on a database.

How do I properly close a server on log out and re open on log in?  Or should I never close the socket?  The same question goes for DataInputStream and DataOutputStream.

I keep getting connection reset client sided, so I don't know what the best way to handle logging in/logging out within the same client runtime.

Thanks. :)

Comment: I already have a sub server of the server socket that is managed by threads.  I'm talking about closing the connection client sided though.

Comment: Something like this: http://pastebin.com/YhNFtpHc

Comment: @MadProgrammer TCP sockets are already full-duplex. You don't need two of them for 'simultaneous, bi-directional communication'.

Comment: I'd imagine that your client will need to be able to detect these resets and attempt to reconnect in the background.  Basically closing the you should close the streams in one `try-catch` (each one should be done separately to ensure best effort), then close the `Socket` in another `try-catch` as the last ditch effort.  Generally speaking, closing the `Socket` should close the streams as well, but it would be nice to try and do it cleanly...

Comment: @MadProgrammer There is no need to close all the socket streams. Just the outermost one wrapped around the output stream. That flushes it, closes the other (input) stream, and the socket. Closing the socket itself in a finally block is nice but in practice unnecessary and mostly omitted.

Comment: @EJP Agreed, but I work in the principle of "you open it, you close it" - but that's just me

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're missing the point. (1) You *must* close the outermost output stream you've wrapped around the socket output stream, otherwise you miss a flush, and (2) you must close that first, before the input stream or the socket, otherwise again you miss a flush. (2) is redundant in any case as I've said. So the simplest solution is just to do (1). Just vaguely handwaving and saying 'close the streams' and 'you open it, you close it' without specifying the required order is insufficient.

Comment: What is the correct order?  Not to sound like it's all about me, but I still need help.  Should I close all at once? Only the Socket, do the streams first?  I'm trying to avoid a connection reset error.

Comment: I've stated that, several times. Close the outermost stream or Writer wrapped around the socket output stream. That flushes it and closes the other streams and the socket.

Answer (score 1):

Just close the socket. That will terminate the corresponding thread at the server. One login should equal one socket.

You should do that by closing the outermost stream or Writer wrapped around the socket output stream. That flushes it and closes the other streams and the socket. Closing the input stream and the socket before this is incorrect, and doing so afterwards is redundant, but if you must do it it must be done after, not before, otherwise again you miss a flush.